# Reactjs application deployment issue

Tags: reactjs

I had deployed Reactjs application build to Control Panel.  Home page is working fine but when I'm Clicking on about or others  page

showing error 404. But when I run application with npm start it is working properly. Could please help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Navigation from '../includes/Navbar.';

import Home from './pages/Home';

import About from './pages/About';

import Services from './pages/Services';

import Projects from './pages/Projects';

import Gallery from './pages/Gallery';

import Contact from './pages/Contact';







class App extends Component {
```

render() {
    return (

```
    <Navigation />
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/services" component={Services} />
        <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects} />
        <Route exact path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>

    <Footer />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

}
}

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pt8s.png) [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjgdr.png)

Comment: what is C Panel? how you do the build?

Comment: c panel is a control panel

Comment: with npm run build in cms

Comment: @Omer CPanel is a Linux-based control panel that is used by many web hosting services. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel.

Comment: Can you post a small example showing some code from your React app? In particular, how are you processing the About page? Are you using react-router or something similar?

Comment: If you're using react router, you need to configure your web server to return your `index.html` page as a fallback so that your app can handle navigation on its own. If you provide more information about your setup, someone can probably provide a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are using .net for serving you react SPA application.

So you need to add this configuration as web.config file to your .net application to support SPA applications.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="SPA" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*(.js|.css|.png|.jpg|.ico|.svg)).*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more information, you can read this blog post:

https://medium.com/medialesson/best-way-to-host-a-single-page-application-spa-in-microsoft-azure-3e70cbd075c3